# List all variables that can be modified during runtime

Tags: mysql, variables, runtime, mysql-variables

Is there any way to get all system variables that can be modified during runtime? I have tested using `SHOW VARIABLES` but this returns all variables and not only the one that can be changed during runtime.

If I use `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES` I get a response starting like this:

```
+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Variable_name                                     | Value                                                                                                                  |
+---------------------------------------------------+------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| auto_increment_increment                          | 1                                                                                                                      |
| auto_increment_offset                             | 1                                                                                                                      |
| autocommit                                        | ON                                                                                                                     |
| automatic_sp_privileges                           | ON                                                                                                                     |
| back_log                                          | 50                                                                                                                     |
| basedir                                           | /usr                                                                                                                   |
| big_tables                                        | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| binlog_cache_size                                 | 32768                                                                                                                  |
| binlog_direct_non_transactional_updates           | OFF                                                                                                                    |
| binlog_format                                     | STATEMENT                                                                                                              |
| binlog_stmt_cache_size                            | 32768                                                                                                                  |
```

The above returns variables like `basedir` which cannot be set during runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `SHOW VARIABLES` with the `SESSION` scope modifier.

EG: `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES`

> SHOW VARIABLES accepts an optional GLOBAL or SESSION variable scope
>   modifier:
>
> With a GLOBAL modifier, the statement displays global system variable
>   values. These are the values used to initialize the corresponding
>   session variables for new connections to MySQL. If a variable has no
>   global value, no value is displayed.
>
> With a SESSION modifier, the statement displays the system variable
>   values that are in effect for the current connection. If a variable
>   has no session value, the global value is displayed. LOCAL is a
>   synonym for SESSION.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-variables.html

Comment: as I understand it some variables can be changed even if they have global scope and the user has correct privileges?

Comment: So long as the user has the correct privileges, yes.

Comment: yes and I would like to get *only* variables that can be modified during runtime, not stuff like log directories and so on. Does your answer still apply in this case?

Comment: Maybe not. I'm not sure. As I understand it it would return all the system variables _available_ for the current connection. I had assumed that these would be modifiable but perhaps that assumption was unfounded.

Comment: I don't think this is correct since `SHOW SESSION VARIABLES` also returns variables like `basedir` which cannot be changed during runtime according to this listing: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/dynamic-system-variables.html